# Trigger Snapshot Dependency to Build Specific Branch in TeamCity

Tags: git, branch, teamcity, snapshot, teamcity-8.0

Let's say I have a project **Foo** configured with Git VCS root having default branch `feature/foo`.  I'd like to have a snapshot dependency on a project **Bar** that is unit testing every feature branch on the same repo as **Foo** (ie, the VCS root for **Bar** has no default branch and is instead watching `feature/*`).

What I see happening is that **Foo** can only trigger builds on **Bar's** `<default>` branch.  Can I change it so that **Bar** gets triggered for the right branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to configure VCS root without default branch in TeamCity (see related issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23395). So if you do not define default branch for Bar build configuration it will be set to master by default. And if you trigger a build with default branch, all dependencies will be triggered with default branch as well.

The solutions is to configure the same branch specification for **Foo** configuration as for **Bar** (feature/*). If you run **Foo** build manually you need to select needed branch using Run Custom Dialog (Changes tab), if you run build using VCS trigger you need to configure Branch filter.

Comment: my mistake, **Bar's** default is set to `develop`.  So, if a default run on **Foo** will _always_ kick off a default run on **Bar**, is there a way to prevent a user from starting a default run on **Foo**?

Comment: As for now I can suggest the workaround described in this [comment](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24147#comment=27-496473). Instead you can check this parameter teamcity.build.branch.is_default=true.